# How is Request.Url.IsDefaultPort determined?

Tags: c#, http, iis

I have what I hope is a simple question that I cannot seem to wrap my head around.  Very plainly how is this line of code determined:

```
Request.Url.IsDefaultPort
```

More often than not it is seen like this:

```
Request.Url.IsDefaultPort ? "" : ":" + Request.Url.Port
```

My question has a few more things involved:

1. Will this be true if my url is: http://www.mysitename.com and IIS is using port 80 for this
2. Will this be true if my url is: http://www.mysitename.com:12345 and IIS is using port 12345 for this
3. Is this the same as saying: Request.Url.Port == 80 ? "" : ":" + Request.Url.Port?

I did check Microsoft's [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.isdefaultport(v=vs.110).aspx) which, as it tends to be, was a little less than helpful.  Here is a quote on how this property is determined: "A Boolean value that is true if the value in the Port property is the default port for this scheme; otherwise, false."  Unfortunately, I have no idea what they mean by the word 'scheme'.

Thank you, in advance, for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is `true` if the port is the default port for *the scheme*. e.g., HTTP as a scheme (`http:`) uses port 80. HTTPS as a scheme (`https:`) uses port 443.

The `Uri.IsDefaultPort` property merely checks if the port value is equal to the default for the scheme, not the binding in IIS.

1. Yes, it will be true for http://www.mysitename.com, on port 80
2. No, it will be false for http://www.mysitename.com:12345 on port 12345
3. Not quite, your example is true, IF you are checking a URI using the `http` scheme: `Request.Url.Port == 80 // this is false for HTTPS, as an example.`

You can check the sheme using the `Uri.Scheme` property (`Request.Url` is an instance of `Uri`).

Comment: Ah, thank you.  This was my suspicion, I didn't put the scheme together, thank you for clearing that up for me.